# What is the distribution of amplitude and phase of circularly symmetric normal random variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, probability-distributions, complex-numbers

If a complex random variable x is  circularly symmetric standard gaussian  $ x = CN (0,1)$ then what we can say about its amplitude and phase.

Answer (score 0):

With circular symmetry the phase in uniform $U[0,2\pi]$, and the amplitude is [half normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution). The phase and amplitude are independent.